# Why can't Dash find some of the applications installed in 15.10?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 15.10

As far as we have got no "start menu" in Ubuntu nowadays we have to use Dash to look up and launch the installed applications. And I have never had any problems with this. But now, as I have installed 15.10 I have found it unable to find many of installed apps (Synaptic, for example). What can be the cause and how can I fix this?

PS: I know how to bring the menu back and I have actually done so but still curious about fixing the Dash.

Comment: Something similar happened to me. After install some application it doesn't appear on the dash until I restart the system. I don't know if is the same case as yours...

Answer (score 0):

Is zeitgeist-daemon working?

If not,

```
zeitgeist-daemon --quit
rm -rvf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist
zeitgeist-daemon --replace &
```